# Access variable from one function to another

Tags: python, list, function

I have a following code snippet in python.

```
class Test():
    def a(self,dct,res_dct,lst):
        url_ls = []
        ....
        return url_ls
   
    def b(self):
        ....
```

I want to access the url_ls from a() to b(). How is it possible?

Comment: take the returned value - `url_ls = self.a(...)`

Comment: Why not making `url_ls` a class attribute? then you can acess it from every method. `self.url_ls`

Comment: alright then i post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize a instance attribut '''self.urls'''.
After that, you can use it in both function (see doc POO)

```
class Test():
def __init__(self):
    self.url_ls = []

def a(self,dct,res_dct,lst):
    self.url_ls = []

def b(self):
    print(self.url_ls)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why not making `url_ls` a class attribute? then you can acess it from every method. `self.url_ls`

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls_ls = []

    def a(self,dct,res_dct,lst):
        url_ls = []
        ....
        self.urls_ls = url_ls
   
    def b(self):
        ....
```